# Where to store socket.io id array

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am building a real time application via socket.io . I want my users to be able to message each other. My question is where should I store the array of connected socket ids. Should I store it just in array on the server? Or should I create a separate DB and store it there?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structure of the application, but I find it convenient to use the Redis database to store and add the socket ID.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Right now I am just storing it in an array on the server. But I will read more about Redis.